# ClickOnce custom prerequisite problem with installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce, installation, bootstrapping

I have created custom prerequisite setup project for ClickOnce and it is among the other prerequisites in publish tab of the project. But when i try to install my app via ClickOnce(with setup button) it runs prerequisite setup, and asks if i want to install it. I click "install" and the following error appears:

> The following package files could not
>   be found: 
>   C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary
>   Internet
>   Files\Content.IE5\U2R49322\FontPrerequisite\setupfont.msi

When i launch the application-it installs it, but without prerequisite. What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but I would assume that you've specified that the user should download the prerequisite from the vendors site.  Open the Prerequisites dialog and select your prerequisite.  Click on the option that states **Download prerequisite from the same location as my application**.  (See the screen shot below)

[image]

This should bundle your prereq with your application deployment.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Made that changes(Download from the following location-helped), but now get the following: Component FontSetup has failed to install with the following error message:
"The operation completed successfully. "

The following components failed to install:
- FontSetup

Comment: That could be a problem with the MSI project.  It sounds to me that when it successfully finishes, it's return the Success state as a failure message.  It's been a long time since I've made an installation project, so I'm not sure if that's possible.  As a test, uninstall the FontSetup on your test environment, and then try directly running the installation MSI (don't download and run it from the ClickOnce page.)  Does the installation give you an error?  If so that could be your problem.  If it works, try the ClickOnce install again and see if it give you the same or different error message.

Comment: ..Gives the same error..Tho it installs the font, but overall installation is stopping on that step.

Comment: Are you "launching" the application from the installation page or are you clicking the Install button?

Comment: Im clicking install button on the installation page. With launch application just launches, without prerequisites installed.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped.  I have been using ClickOnce for quite some time and I've seen bugs like this.  The semi-good news is that they tend to be specific to one user or computer install instance.  I'd try it again on another PC and see if you get the same message.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @RLH I have create a custom package for a prerequisite I need.. but I can't see it in the Prerequisites list.. how can I see it? i have put in the same dir of the other prerequisites (VS2013)

Comment: @PieroAlberto  It's been a few years since I've had to manage a ClickOnce project, and I'd have to dig into the nuance changes over the past few years.  I suggest posting a new question.  Sorry.

Comment: @RLH  I've just restarted the visual studio session! =)